# Ho to run test complete project using command line?

Tags: automation, testcomplete

I have a TestComplete project, called: automation.pjs, which contains some tests.

I want to run those tests using the command line and observe the results in the command line too.

I'm using TestComplete 14 on Windows OS.

Is it possible? Which command shall I run?
Do I need to download a specific plugin?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/working-with/automating/command-line-and-exit-codes/command-line.html

You can also input these commands into windows task scheduler to have them run periodically!

-specify the path to your testcomplete.exe, input arguments such as /r, /e, /p etc.

e.g

cd ..\..\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestComplete 14\Bin 
TestComplete.exe "C:\Users\user.name\documents\ProjectSuite1\automation.pjs" /r /e

Comment: If you are affiliated with the site you are linking to, you need to explicitly disclose this. See also [How not to be a spammer.](/help/promotion)